# Hosting Pyramid webapps under subpaths

Tags: python, hosting, pyramid

We have a hosting setup where we have one top level domain, and we host web applications under subpaths. For instance:

```
  /projects -> Plone
  /interal -> Tomcat
  etc
```

In this scenario we need a way to tell the web application at the back end what its base path is, so that it can correctly generate links to its views and static content. For the examples above this is fine.

We have just started using Pyramid, served by Waitress, but so far we've not figure out how to do this. Is there a clean way to configure this base path in Waitress, or is there a more flexible application server that we can use that will support Pyramid?

Comment: I assume you're using a different front-facing web server that proxies all of these path->appserver requests? It might be easiest to do the desired path-trim on that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Everything in WSGI is relative to the current request. You just have to have your `environ` setup properly (usually by your WSGI server).

For example your web application will know it is mounted at subpath `/projects` if `request.environ['SCRIPT_NAME'] == '/projects'`. If you want your application to be agnostic to its mount point, you can simply code it up as if it serves a view at `/foo/bar`. Then you mount your application on `/projects` via some middleware which can mutate the `environ` properly (mod_wsgi and some other servers should be able to do this for you automatically). Now when the incoming URL is `/projects/foo/bar` the `environ['SCRIPT_NAME'] == '/projects'` and `environ['PATH_INFO'] == '/foo/bar'`, and your app can focus on the relative path.

In Pyramid this would boil down to an extra step in your ini where you add the prefix middleware to your WSGI stack. The middleware handles mutating the `PATH_INFO` and `SCRIPT_NAME` keys in the `environ` for you.

```
[app:myapp]
use = egg:myapp

# ...

[filter:proxy-prefix]
use = egg:PasteDeploy#prefix
prefix = /projects

[pipeline:main]
pipeline =
    proxy-prefix
    myapp
```

Comment: Thank you, it's clear I need to learn a lot more about WSGI and move beyond just following recipes. I've also had it suggested that I could (alternatively) use egg:repoze.vhm#vhm_path in the pipeline.

Comment: VHM only works for traversal and has a few caveats such as mainly being useful for *generating* urls. But sure, it might be another option for you.

Answer (score 0):

In my pyramid app, in the .ini config files (production and development) I'm doing something like this:

```
filter-with = urlprefix

[filter:urlprefix]
use = egg:PasteDeploy#prefix
prefix = /mysubfolder
```

I think it probably accomplishes the same as Michael's answer above; I'm still relatively new to Pyramid as well and am going off of recipes like you.  But the end result is that it creates a base URL of /mysubfolder from my root and the rest of the app is relative to that.  This is running under pserve locally and I think nginix on my web host.

Answer (score 0):

repoze.vhm should work just fine for your use case.

I think it won't work if you want to use the virtual root feature. I.e a subpath of your proxied web app (*https://hidden.tld/root/* should appear as *https://example.com/* )

For exposing your app at a subpath of an external domain repoze.vhm works just fine. IMO the  best thing about it is, that you don't need to put any subpath config or whatsoever into your web app deployment. This allows you to change the url to whatever you want on the proxy, or even expose the same app instance on multiple domain names and/or subpaths.